# MVC add to JSON object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add many json lists to another json object to send to the view, however I am not sure how to add all of them to a single object as it is not always certain how many lists there will be.

Here is what I have so far in my controller, I get each list from a LINQ query from my model and convert it to a list that is stored in a var.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
//Actions for Export                      //
///////////////////////////////////////////
public JsonResult GetInfoToExport()
{
    using (InsertModelEntities dc = new InsertModelEntities())
    {
        CleintEntities cleints = new CleintEntities();
        var ClientList = cleints.Clients.ToList();

        var JsonToSend = new JsonResult();

        foreach (var Company in ClientList)
        {
            var ClientInfo = (from E in dc.EventsAllLocations
                              join C in cleints.Clients on E.CompanyName equals C.Company
                              where C.Company == Company.ToString() && E.Start.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && E.Start.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
                              select new
                              {
                                  Company = E.CompanyName,
                                  Location = E.Location,
                                  HoursPaid = C.HoursPayed,
                                  Start = E.Start,
                                  End = E.End,
                                  Time = E.End - E.Start
                              }).ToList();
            JsonToSend.
            //Not sure how to add each of these ClientInfo list items to the JsonToSend object
        }




        return new JsonResult { Data = JsonToSend, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

I want to be able to add each **ClientInfo** list to the **JsonToSend** Object and just send that, but looking online I cant find any syntax on how to do this. Any help or nudge in the right direction will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance! :)

Edit:

Also tried:

```
        List<JsonResult> bookings = new List<JsonResult>();

       // var JsonToSend = new JsonResult();

        foreach (var Company in ClientList)
        {
            var ClientInfo = (from E in dc.EventsAllLocations
                              join C in cleints.Clients on E.CompanyName equals C.Company
                              where C.Company == Company.ToString() && E.Start.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && E.Start.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
                              select new
                              {
                                  Company = E.CompanyName,
                                  Location = E.Location,
                                  HoursPaid = C.HoursPayed,
                                  Start = E.Start,
                                  End = E.End,
                                  Time = E.End - E.Start
                              }).ToList();
            bookings.Add(ClientInfo);
            //Not sure how to add each of these ClientInfo list items to the JsonToSend object
        }
```

and getting the error

> "Cannot convert from generic list to syste.web.mvc.JsonResult"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually convert the data into a List<> before returning it to the View, like below.

```
public JsonResult GetInfoToExport()
{
    CleintEntities cleints = new CleintEntities();
    var ClientList = cleints.Clients.ToList();
    List<object> ReturnData = new List<object>();
    foreach (var Company in ClientList)
    {
       ReturnData.Add(new { CompanyName = Company.Name, ID = Company.ID // 
       etc });
    }
    return Json(new { Data = ReturnData }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You can then access the JSON object data on the view like such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function GetClientData()
{
      $.ajax({
      url: '/Controller/GetInfoToExport,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST' // use POST to avoid IE caching JavaScript data
      success: function (data)
      {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.length; i++)
            {
                  document.getElementById('someelement').innerHTML += '<label id="C' + data.Data[i].ID +'">' + data.Data[i].CompanyName + '</label><br>';
            }
      }});
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, This worked, ran into a LINQ problem now, but shouldnt be too tough to fix!                 List<object> ReturnData = new List<object>();

ReturnData.Add(ClientInfo);